# How to fix error 'Name: The specified name is not allowed: _destroy'?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have looked at similar questions that suggest I should use the column attribute to change the name of the column, but I have done this and I still get the error. Here is my Model class:

```
public class Task
{
    public int TaskID { get; set; }
    public string TaskDescription { get; set; }
    public bool IsDone { get; set; }

    [Column("Active")]
    public bool _destroy { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that Entity Framework does not allow entity property names to begin with underscore characters (among other character classes). Using Reflector, I was able to track down the regex used to validate property names, and it is the following:

```
@"[\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Lm}\p{Nl}][\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Lm}\p{Nl}\p{Mn}\p{Mc}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}\p{Cf}]{0,}"
```

This means that entity property names can begin only with characters taken from the following Unicode character classes:

Ll, Lu, Lt, Lo, Lm, Nl

The remaining characters in a property name may include those classes, as well as the following:

Mn, Mc, Nd, Pc, Cf

The underscore character (U+005F) is in the Pc class. You can remove the error by renaming the _destroy property as, say destroy. You can find a character class reference [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm).