# Why is a Property starting with an underscore not allowed in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, naming-conventions

When you try to name a property in the Entity Framework designer to a name with an underscore, you'll get the following error: `Navigation Name '_PropertyName' is not valid.`

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10854740/647845

Why is this limitation added? It feels rather arbitrary to me.

Answer (score 2):

The EF source code is available (http://entityframework.codeplex.com/) so we can take a look directly, no need to rely on some form of decompilation.

A search for regexes shows this:

```
// Replace anything that doesn't adhere to the ECMA specification for identifiers with an underscore,
// unless it's the first which the schema definition says must be a letter...
// System.Data.Resource.CSMSL_2.xsd - [\p{L}\p{Nl}][\p{L}\p{Nl}\p{Nd}\p{Mn}\p{Mc}\p{Pc}\p{Cf}]{0,}
```

in [`src/EFTools/EntityDesignModel/ModelHelper.cs`](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EFTools/EntityDesignModel/ModelHelper.cs).

Looking for that schema file: cannot be found, but changing it to `System.Data.Resources.CSMSL_2.xsd` shows three files: one in `setup` and one in `test` which I'll assume are copies of the third: [`src/EntityFramework/Resources/System/Data/MappingSpecification/System.Data.Resources.CSMSL_2.xsd`](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/Resources/System/Data/MappingSpecification/System.Data.Resources.CSMSL_2.xsd).

This does indeed use the same regex as a constraint on the `TSimpleIdentifier` type.

Thus, to answer your question:

> Why is this limitation added? It feels rather arbitrary to me.

Because this is the limit on the underlying EF Model imposes. To understand why you'll need to ask those that designed the EF at the beginning.

Yes, it *is* arbitrary. But then all identifier naming rules are arbitary. Eg.

- Some things allow a hyphen and not underscores in names, but those cannot be directly mapped to .NET identifiers
- C# and F# allow a different subset of .NET CLR identifiers (F# identifiers can include spaces!)
- This is how anonymous types in C# can have a name at runtime but cannot be named in source code: the `<` and `>` characters that appear in the compiler generated names are fine for the CLR's runtime.